# NDSOlve - 1D wave equation with boundary

Tags: differential-equations

I am currently trying to solve the 1D wave equation with Mathematica:

$$c^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t^2}$$
I want to do so for a cantilever with a tip mass:

[image: a busy cat]

One Side is fixed the other one has the movable tip mass. The mass obeys this condition: 
$$ M \ddot{u}(L,t)=-EAu'(l,t) \Rightarrow u'(l,t)=-k\cdot \ddot{u}(L,t)$$ 
To solve the equation we need 2 boundary and 2 initial conditions. The system starts with an initial velocity $v_0$ out of rest:
$$
\begin{array}
\dot{u}(l,0)&=-v_0 \\
u(x,0)      &=0 \\
u(0,t)      &=0 \\
u'(l,t)     &=-k\cdot\ddot{u}(l,t)
\end{array}
$$

I am able to solve it with pen and paper, but I want to further study the resulting fourier series. Therefore I want to implement this in Mathematica.

```
c = 1; k = 1; v = 1; L=1;
BOUN1 = k*Derivative[0, 2][u][L, t] + Derivative[1, 0][u][L, t] == 0;
BOUN2 = u[0, t] == 0;
INIT1 = u[x, 0] == 0;
INIT2 = Derivative[0, 1][u][L, 0] == -v;

DEQN1 = c^2*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] - D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == 0 ;

SOLU1= NDSolveValue[{DEQN1,BOUN1,BOUN2,INIT1,INIT2 }, u, {x,0,L}, {t,0,1}]
```

Can someone help me solve the problems I am facing with the boundary conditions? The Error message is:

> INIT2 is not specified on a single edge of the boundary of the computational \
>   domain.

I tried defining it over the entire domain with an diracDelta, but with no effect. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I get `Derivative[0, 1][u][1, 0]` instead of `INIT2`, suggesting that you haven't evaluated `INIT2`.  But I get an error because `Derivative[0, 1][u][L, 0] == -v` specifies a condition at a point, not along an edge.  There seem to be other issues, too, such as `BOUN1` not having only derivatives of order less than `DEQN1`.  There are several wave equation questions on this site here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=wave+equation

Comment: Defining INIT2 as Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == -v DiracDelta[x - L] might fix that problem. Which leaves me with a problem with BOUN1. The condition I described is correct but maybe not properly defined. But even if I remove the second time derivative by setting k=0 I can't get a solution. Tricky...Of course I checked similar questions first but this did not help with this boundary related problem.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to add the cantilever bc `Derivative[1,0][u][0,t]==0`, but then I get error about non-linear Dirichlet condition, which I believe is still a limitation of the current `DSolve`.